# GridStack- Setting the static grids

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridstack

I am trying to make the grids static. No movement at all.

I tried:

```
var options = {
        staticGrid: true,
    };
    $('.grid-stack').gridstack(options);
```

and also this

```
 var options = {
        setStatic: true,
    };
    $('.grid-stack').gridstack(options);
```

and this

```
var options = {
        staticGrid: true,
    };
    $('.grid-stack').gridstack(options);
    $('.grid-stack').data('gridstack').setStatic(true);
```

None of them seems to work, I used this [link](https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js/tree/develop/doc#options) for documentation.

They have also mentioned a method [setStatic](https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js/tree/develop/doc#setstaticstaticvalue) but there are no examples of usign this method.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Gridstack docs](https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js/tree/develop/doc#disable) the **staticGrid:true** parameter is correct if you want to initialise and define the grid as STATIC at startup (your first method).

The SetStatic(true) is a function you can call on for toggling this state programatically.

If you view the source code live you will see a new CSS class has been added to the grid wrapper DIV; a class called '**grid-stack-static**'. The appearance of this class confirms the parameter option **staticGrid:true** has been accepted and actioned.

BUT as I found myself (with v0.30 of the library), grid widgets in my initialised grid are still resizable and movable. In my opinion this suggests a bug.

You can lock down movement and resizing at a widget item level by using the item attributes **data-gs-no-resize="yes"** and **data-gs-no-move="yes"**.

Seems counterproductive to have to do this if you have said 'static' already.

I have lodged an issue on [Github](https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js/issues/743) to query this behaviour.

BTW it has been suggested to call on and use the **setStatic( true )** function after grid init; as a temporary fix for this bug. Which was **your third method** - AND this worked for me.

Only difference between your 3rd method and mine is the function is wrapped in a document.ready function (and I am using $=jquery shortcut for convenience/compatibility on my system).

Worked:

```html
(function ($) { 
  // Shortcut $=jquery

    $(document).ready(function () {
      // start grid

      $(function () {
        var options = {
             staticGrid:true
          };
         $('.grid-stack').gridstack(options);

         $('.grid-stack').data('gridstack').setStatic( true );
      });

    // END DOC READY
    }); 
// SHORTCUT FIX
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: @Kamran the workaround WILL also work on inner grids. Repeat the API call setStatic(true) for each grid group construct class name. i.e $('.grid-inner').data('gridstack').setStatic( true );

Comment: Dev branch of Gridstack has been patched and issue resolved. The code above still has merit for showing different ways of enabling static-mode.

Comment: This will work in the currently released version of gridstack.

Comment: To fix this issue use the development (not production) fork of Gridstack. See Issue 743 [link](https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/issues/743) for info.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the attribute `gs-static="true"`on the grid-stack's parent Grid element (on which gridstack has been initialized).

```
<div class="grid-stack" gs-static="true">
  <div class="grid-stack-item">
    <div class="grid-stack-item-content">Item 1</div>
  </div>
<!-- .. and so on -->
</div
```